# Uniform Buffers in WebGL?

Tags: webgl

Are there WebGL UniformBuffers? Because there doesn't seem to be an `gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER` anywhere. Are they just named differently then in OpenGL or do they not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniform Buffers are in WebGL2 but not WebGL1

See [all these questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwebgl2%5D+uniform+buffers)

This is because WebGL1 is based on OpenGL ES 2.0 which does not have Uniform Buffers

WebGL2 is based on OpenGL ES 3.0 which does have Uniform Buffers.